# How did my answer get downvoted immediately?

Tags: discussion, support, answers, downvotes

I have [answered a question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68776582/776348) and right after I have pushed the post button I saw that it was already downvoted. Right from the first moment that it was published!

I wonder how is that's possible.

**Edit after finally improving my original answer**: I have improved my original answer after asking this question and digesting the answers, since my original intent of asking this question was not related to quality of my answer.

PS: I agree that my initial answer was incomplete (and partly wrong, but the idea was correct) and I get that I needed to improve it.

**Acknowledgement**: This was by far the best experience that I had with SO community so far. I think I (kind of) understand what the problem is. The problem is that my attempt to "answer first, edit/correct right after" failed due to the flaw in my answer. So it can clearly be said that my ambition to get those *unicorn points* led me to a failure to contribute.

Comment: Your answer doesn't even give the result OP wants, second slice should index to `-7`, not `-6`. Even then, it will only work for that specific list size, if the source list `a` was any other size the result wouldn't be as expected (last 3 elements plus first 4)

Comment: Most likely, someone was currently viewing the question, saw your answer, and decided it wasn't useful, instantly.

Comment: You might have wanted to improve your answer *before* posting this meta question

Comment: One of the 30 people who opened the question was viewing it -> they got the update for a new answer -> saw your answer -> took them literal seconds to read and understand because it's so short -> they decided it was not useful and downvoted it. Mystery solved!

Comment: You misunderstand "SUPER QUICK" to be "instantaneous". I mean... genuinely, how long does it take to review that answer? all of 1-2 seconds? you hit post, your page loads. While it does, I click "view answer", and I read and downvote. Is *that* sequence of events possible?

Comment: @AndrewMorton While good advice, is sloppy grammar and spelling a downvote reason? I always thought it was an reason to edit.

Comment: There have been many times I've seen an answer posted and been able to tell within an eye blink whether or not it was correct. I'll usually comment on why it's wrong before I donwnvote because I hate it when the question's deleted half way through writing the explanatory comment.

Comment: @AndrewMorton How can we be sure OP wasn't referring to the Sith?

Comment: slightly related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379284/watch-those-itchy-trigger-fingers

Comment: maybe helpful: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/380187/questions-of-mine-getting-downvoted-how-can-i-become-a-better-community-member?rq=1

Comment: @rene:  I really want a canonical FGITW/SCITE kind of Q&A on MSO since this is textbook that.

Comment: @Makoto sure, but your current answer isn't that canonical if you ask me. So now what?

Comment: *"right after I have pushed the post button I saw that it was already downvoted. Right from the first moment that it was published!"* ... that's a very inaccurate and exaggerated way to describe 46 seconds.

Comment: @rene:  Didn't say it was. I'm just stating what I want and what I think could've been a better dupe target than the one you provided earlier.  I was close to letting it go, but there were no comments on the OP's answer...

Comment: @Makoto I was still looking for dupes and was highly surprised when I couldn't add another one only to find you beat me to it by re-opening. Anyway: this search is relevant then: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=fastest+gun+

Comment: Although what happened was totally my fault, I believe that I have asked an honest and valid question. So I do not understand the reason behind the lots of downvotes here. :)

Comment: @Tom are you certain that it took 46 seconds someone to downvote my answer?

Comment: Yes I am, all timestamps are stored on this site.

Comment: @BedirYilmaz *"So I do not understand the reason behind the lots of downvotes here"* - I don't consider this question useful in any way, there's a possible reason. Other people will have other reasons

Comment: Well then we have different opinions, since the answer that I got was pretty useful for me :) I would not have stopped and thought about why I tried to answer fast and and risked to be less accurate if I did not get Makoto's answer @Nick

Comment: Of course, people have different ideas of what is useful, so while you might find it useful (why else would you ask it), others won't necessarily

Comment: And still... the answer remains unimproved. Is anyone else a bit surprised at this?

Comment: @Nick you're right.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I did improve my answer a little bit, but there is still room for improvement. I am still reading the answers and comments to my own question here. I ask for your patience and invite you to not to read the minds of others (only a suggestion though).

Comment: Yes @gnat, it is certainly helpful. It resonates with the understanding that I have reached.

Comment: @BedirYilmaz - We can only read what you have written.  If you have to clarify something you have written and want to avoid downvotes due to what you have written, you should edit your own words.

Comment: @SecurityHound I see this as an incentive for the species to evolve telepathy.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You are the [Fastest Gun in the West](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22368/175248).  In effect, you've answered this question without a whole lot of correctness or accuracy, or incentive to be correct or accurate in the first place; you went in with full speed in mind.  In this light, your answers are less likely to be accurate; you yourself acknowledge that your answer was incomplete or wrong.

The immediate, guttural response to someone posting an answer so blazingly fast and so barren is usually to downvote it, since it's not all *that* useful.  You don't add more to the pool of collective knowledge in the question than the other answerer.

If you want to have a lower risk of downvotes, then you should take your time with your answers.  Yes, you'll miss out on those easy unicorn points. But you won't lose them as fast, either.