# Commenting on old question where the answer didn't work for my code

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, old-questions, comment-replies

I have a question that has been asked before. But for some reason, the answer does not work for my code.

Normally I would ask a new question and link to the old question because the old question was slightly different. But this time, it's a simple question that's exactly what I want to ask.

I have checked, the user who answered the question is active, so they should see my question. But my problem is that I can't show all my code in a comment.

Do I post a link to my code in the comment? I don't know what the proper etiquette for this is.

Comment: If there's more than one answer, don't forget to consider them as possible solutions. It's obvious but sometimes folks miss that.

Comment: @Will I'll keep that in mind. The answer to the old question pointed to [something in the documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.event.html#kivy.event.EventDispatcher.setter) that I had miraculously open in a previous tab at the time. I've been struggling with this issue for a couple of days, and this really seems like the most elegant solution to my problem. If my problem wasn't about Kivy, I would absolutely be open to different solutions.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57050377/problems-with-property-binding-and-styling-in-kivy) is apparently now the new question.

Comment: No one mentioned [bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) yet, but that's the correct way to act for exact duplicate if you need more answers (because none of existing works for you). If your question is somewhat different (e.g. you have different requirement), simply ask a new one and don't forgot to link to duplicate and explain why it is not duplicate and (optionally, but is a good idea) why existing answers doesn't work for you. Without such link and explanation you are risking what someone will just close your question as duplicate.

Comment: @Sinatr Agreed, however, this is not an option for OP because the privilege to [set bounties](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) is award at 75 rep points.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If the question really *is* simple, that means:

- It's complete and concise
- It's likely not a duplicate and you can prove it
- You've got enough context into the specific problem such that your specific desired answer is narrow

...which implies that it's good enough to ask as a full-fledged question.

Comment: I would add that the new question should demonstrate exactly how it is different from the "old question", and preferably (but not obligatorily) show what research has been done into how those differences might affect the answer.

Comment: The _original_ [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46845132/bind-property-to-another-property-in-kivy) was simple. It's asked more elegantly than I could have asked, and has the same reasoning behind it. So I'm not very confident that I can show that my question is different. I just want to know why the answer doesn't work for my code, and how to fix it.

Comment: Well it turns out I don't have enough reputation to even make a comment on the old question. So I'm going to have to make a new question anyways.

Comment: @FergusWyrm: FYI: You are only missing 8 reputation points before you get the privilege to comment. [This Q&A](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252149/2675154) contains some tips how to close the gap.

Comment: @honk: In all seriousness, if someone has a new question, they should ask the new question.  Commenting on it would only serve to muddy the water for both the OP and the person they want help from.

Comment: @Makoto: I'm sorry, I didn't mean to counter your arguments. This is why I wrote "FYI" and not "No, please comment instead" ;)

Comment: That's fine; I knew your intent wasn't do to that but a lot of people take comments as gospel, so I wanted to be explicit on what needed to happen in this context.

Comment: Fine for me ;) IMHO, you are doing an excellent job on Meta! I'm happy that you are still around after all...

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion, **this is the whole point of the link, and Related section on the side of the page.**

"Related" becomes more and more irrelevant the more we insist that questions are duplicates when there are practical differences between the two.

This is a Q&A site where the code-focused StackExchange sites and StackOverflow rather serves as, for all intents and purposes, a chrestomathy for a given language.

As such, if a solution does not actually work for the situation, then functionally I would say that's a new question. Whatever algorithm is used for Related (linked, inverse document frequency, etc), people on the old question and the new questions should see the relation between the two.

At the end of the day, your question serves as a historical record. Five years from now, someone might look at that question and be misled - costing time or even money - and this is your opportunity to save that person. I know I get very annoyed when I look at an answer from years ago and the answer is very lazy, obtuse, or even rude and it has upvotes, and I've gained nothing from the research.

But if you link them, or at  least ensure your question is explained clearly and concisely, then that's great.

Commenting gets in the way of all of that.