# How do I get enough reputation points without asking duplicate questions?

Tags: discussion

I've been on Stack Overflow for close to two years now, and I've never had to ask a question because most of the time, I find whatever question that comes to mind has already been asked and I'd only be submitting a duplicate question.

I do, however, feel the need to follow up sometimes on a question by commenting, to get clarity from the person that answers, which I can't because I don't have enough reputation points.

I would like to know, how am I expected to gain the necessary reputation points if after so long, I've only had questions that have already been asked and answered? Wouldn't it make sense to allow a person to be able to comment, regardless of reputation points, for the reason that I've already stated?

Comment: You can get points for answering questions.

Comment: Please read: [How does a new user get started on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252149/2675154)

Comment: See [How does “Reputation” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7237/289905), [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/214173/289905).