# Do we have any chance as a new contributor?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, new-users

I am keep trying to use stackoverflow in a best way whether I ask or reply the question recently. You could see it from my recent history as well. Once I ask a new question yesterday, one commenter blamed me that I am patronising other contributor with the following comment:

> "If you read carefully, you will see that "G" means the student has
> not attended. For that reason, if he got this scenario with 10, G, 0,
> I have to choose 10 and 0 as quiz inputs. Because 0 is better than G
> because of attendance side. If there is a result (with numbers), it
> means that student has already attended. It is pretty simple and the
> data is purely tidy!"

The same person closed my question because of the lack of information. However, before closing the question he tried to give an answer there. If the question is not properly asked, how can he reply it before closing it? In addition, I have properly explained why it is tidy etc. There is no counter-argument for that.

If somebody targets me through stackoverflow, how can I save myself as a new contributor? Is it everything consist of numbers, rankings, votes ? If we are just starting to use stackoverflow properly, do we have any chance as a new contributor?

Comment: This seems like an utter exaggeration. Someone thought your question was unclear, and now you are claiming to have been "targeted", and posturing as if this somehow prevents you from ever getting started using Stack Overflow. With that attitude, it is indeed going to be difficult to get started. Consider that the people trying to help you are not just being deliberately obtuse. If they don't understand or think your question is unclear, you only do yourself a favor by trying to clarify it.

Comment: Here is a useful answer explaining how to get started on SO https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252149/how-does-a-new-user-get-started-on-stack-overflow

Comment: Moderation doesn't mean you're being targeted. While we're at it, downvotes and moderation action taken against you shouldn't be taken personally. It's because of your post, not because if you (AKA if you get downvoted, that means "this post is bad", NOT "this post is bad, and you should feel bad about yourself for posting it"). ". "However, before closing the question he tried to give an answer there." - Some people answer and then vote to close. I'll never understand why (with exception of cases where the close vote leads to self-deletion of the answer, because misunderstandings (1/x)

Comment: are fairly common. It's also possible to find a dupe target after answering.). "If somebody targets me through stackoverflow, how can I save myself as a new contributor?" - this case wasn't targeting. Serial voting is targeting (emphasis on "serial" - not just regular voting), and CoC violating comments targeting you from an objective standpoint is targeting. There are more examples of targeting, but moderation isn't one of them. There was nothing over the line in this case, and if there ever is, flag the comment(s) and/or relevant post(s). Also, if you wanna make it on Stack (2/3)

Comment: you only really have a chance if you believe you do. If you believe everyone is out to get you and wants you to fail, then you will. If, on the other hand, you assume good faith in others and have some faith in yourself, you'll get a lot further on the site.

Comment: I would like to make a little bit awareness here with this question. Some of them keep going to follow the previous trajectory, others are supporting me either with comments or votes. Appreciate with the support. I think I cannot persuade those here, but be aware that various new developers are leaving active contribution side just because of similar issues.

Comment: You should always assume people commenting are participating in good faith.  You question is perfectly clear to you because you wrote the question and spend a lot of time with the data.  But for someone who only has the info you provide in the question, it might be harder to understand.  The best course of action is to have a trusted friend/schoolmate/colleague read the question and offer their insight.  The user who answered and closed may have been trying to help by taking a guess but still thought there were issues with the question

Comment: _"be aware that various new developers are leaving active contribution side just because of similar issues"_ Please try not to conflate new Stack Overflow users with new developers. It makes discussion more ambiguous and fosters some misconceptions. Question asking skills are not directly proportional to programming skills, after all.

Answer (score 14):

> Do we have any chance as a new contributor?

You did have a chance here, but that chance was bashed for not following the recommendations in the [code of conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct). Quoting, emphasis mine:

> **Be clear and constructive when giving feedback, and *be open when receiving it*.**
>
> Edits, *comments*, and suggestions are healthy parts of our community.

Instead of taking constructive feedback and working with it to improve the question, the comment that you quoted above is an indication that you adopted a more defensive stance and insisted that the question was already clear enough. This is an extremely risky move in a site where the volunteers are the ones who contribute with answers, as well as with content curation. The rest of this meta question seems to suggest that the intervenients of your question were in the wrong, but it's up to everyone to do their part. The current prose of the code of conduct lacks an explicit ***"assume good intentions"***, but it does work well here.

Moreover, note that these things happen *regardless of whether you're a new contributor*. It just seems to happen more often to those who are not experienced in the mechanics of the site. The ultimate recommendation here is not to give up over one poor experience. Keep on learning, and there will be more opportunities to contribute to the site.