# Observation from Site Analytics: fewer questions are being asked

Tags: discussion, site-analytics

I've had a look on the Site Analytics page. I displayed the full historical range, questions only, weekly. There is a pronounced yearly oscillation, spring being the most active season (and we can clearly observe why the Christmas hats were introduced).

My interest is elsewhere, however: the long-term trend. Here is the screenshot as described above, annotated by me with a trendline:

[image: Time graph of weekly question volume 2008-today]

A prominent feature comes out: steady growth just up to about mid-2014, then a marked slump. If we take care to compare the same week in different years (to eliminate the effect of the yearly oscillation), we can see that for the months of March and April (normally the busiest ones) there was an actual *drop* in question volume.

What would be a good explanation of this? On the bottom graph I looked at Visits for the same setup as above. It doesn't show the same slump, rather a steady decline in growth rate.

[image: Time graph of weekly visits volume 2008-today]

Comment: I'm no data scientist but it would seem to me that at a certain point the volume of available answers would cut into new question volume/growth trends

Comment: I do see a relatively large decrease in the amount of answers vs questions, around march / april '13 (Show q / a from 2012-today) Did any rules change around that time?

Comment: Eh, 2014 indeed.

Comment: @charlietfl That should show a _gradual_ effect, modulating the growth rate at all times. It shouldn't show any sudden threshold effects.

Comment: Can you add a link or screenshot of the page you reference?

Comment: @moooeeeep That's a new privilege for 25k+ rep users (SO, 5k+ rep on beta sites iirc), so a link's not worth much to many users :)

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik If the rate of development of technologies for which new answers are needed is slower than the rate at which those answers are provided on SE, it could certainly be a threshold effect. Imagine one million dedicated, all-knowing answerers. After the initial answering of everything, there would only be small bursts of activity whenever something new and confusing was invented.

Comment: @sirdank That's a very simplified model. Even accepting the premise there would be gradual decline as the problem space is explored from the general into the specific, into the esoteric. Fat tail distribution would apply.

Comment: There have been prior musings about what exactly happened in late April of 2014 to cause the voting and posting patterns to change.  Already covered well in [this Q+A](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303898/sudden-change-in-voting-proportion).

Comment: @HansPassant There's not a word there about the question volume. I'd say this is much more substantial than the up/down vote ratio.

Comment: The specific date and event is what matters of course, what you are asking about.  You can surely connect the dots from there by using the graph.

Comment: @HansPassant But I'm talking about an effect which is mostly pronounced in _this year's_ March/April. Is your suggestion that the same effect has been persisting from spring 2014 onwards? There is BTW a clear sudden drop in _answer_ volume at the date you mention, but not in _questions_.

Comment: @pnuts I tried to explain it in the edited text. I refer to the comparison of, say, the 1st week of March in each year. This is completely insensitive to the yearly oscillations. Another similar but simpler metric would be total yearly volume of questions.

Comment: Is there any correlation with the release of new moderator tools? Triage, gold badge close hammer, etc? SO has *really* ramped up it's efforts to filter crap questions out. I could see this having a negative impact on participation.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot I already invested quite a bit of effort to emphasize that i am not talking about the slump in the curve, but rather a slump in the _yearly growth rate_, comparing same dates (weeks actually) in successive years. The growth rate was actually negative this year. BTW I mention that in the second paragraph (first one is obviously just introduction).

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot I annotated the picture with a trendline to make it obvious without  trying hard to see it.

Comment: @pnuts When you compare as I originally did, week for week, the conclusions are not the same as when you just slash a straight red line through it all. Many effects are in superposition here and global trend is just one.

Comment: The trend line helps, thanks. (Even though it's *clearly* not freehand...) ;P

Comment: @pnuts Any explanation of such a mechanical kind would require a stark, sudden drop at the day of rule change. This graph looks like the same rules were used to track volume at all times. Compare this with the _answers_ curve, and even than one is not due to mechanical changes in accounting.

Comment: @pnuts Buth there _was_ a sudden drop in answer volume and it was permanent. The answers curve just closed in on the questions curve and maintains the new, shorter distance. I would suggest that this has to do with binding close votes because it reduces the opportunity to add in irrelevant answers. The same cannot apply to questions.

Comment: Wouldn't it be more valuable to look at the trend for new answers instead of new questions, in terms of measuring overall health?  Or rather, since there's likely a strong correlation between the number of new questions asked and the number of new answers provided, what we probably want to look at is the ratio of 'new answers : new questions' in order to get a more accurate snapshot of site health.  A gradual drop-off in the rate of new questions (and therefore, answers) might be expected over time.  A decrease in the proportion of 'answers : questions' might signal an issue, however.

Comment: @aroth There is no evidence of a _gradual_ dropoff in the rate of new questions. The growth rate was the same for 5 years, then a sudden change happened within the last 15 months. The growth rate of _site visits_ experiences a gradual slowdown, though.

Comment: @aroth As for the answer/question ratio, it experienced a sharp fall mid-2014, but from then on it has been stable at the new, lower value.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik - Actually, based upon [what I'm seeing](http://aroth.no-ip.org:65534/so_answer_rate.png), answer/question ratio has been on a steady downward trend for basically all of time (the chart uses a weekly breakdown, to get rid of the jitter).  Although you're correct, over the last ~6 months it has stabilized, and even gained a small bit of ground back from its all-time low.

Comment: @aroth If you look at what [site analytics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/N3H0v.png) presents, you'll see that your graph does not match it. I don't know what are the differences between the data sources, but clearly they are present.

Comment: it's very strange that **year** is not indicated on the x-axis of the first chart

Comment: @joe It's a screenshot from the Site Analytics page.

Comment: Hi Joe, sure, I wasn't "blaming you" but it's very strange that year is not indicated on the x-axis of the first chart

Comment: I thank you for posting the interesting graphs.  Both are totally unlabelled so I have no idea what they mean ... site visits ( or?) what .. per month? total? per hour?

Comment: @joe The text of the question gave you no clues? "Full historical range, questions only, weekly."

Comment: your first graph is completely typical of how dotcoms grow then flatten out. you're supposed to sell-out before they flatten out.  your second graph shows a gentle decline in growth.  that is definitely unquestionably what the graphs show - it's somewhat unclear what you're asking; do you mean "have I read these graphs right?"  if you're wondering "why has SE flattened out" that is unanswerable. ("it's not trendy nay more" .. whatever .. who could know?)

Comment: so the top graph, the y axis is **number of questions asked per week** ... got it, thanks.  what the hecks's the bottom one?

Comment: @aroth Thank you for your responses---they corrected my thinking and now I developed an improved conjecture which might explain the data (see the answer I added).

Comment: Maybe everybody knows everything by now? :)

Comment: @biziclop Sure thing, as evident from a quick visit to the [java] homepage :)

Comment: There are just so many programmers in the world and the more answers that are added to SO, the higher the chance that the question has already been asked.

Comment: @Lundin As already discussed above, that cannot explain any _sudden_ change in the question volume. The effects of what you mention have been present from Day One and are incorporated into the historical growth rate, which would have been greater without the effect.

Comment: @JoeBlow The x-axis is time.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I don't think a decline in questions asked is necessarily a decline in interest. The only thing we can see is that there is a decline in question asking, so maybe we could posit that there's a decline in interest to ask a question, but not much more.

Comment: @TylerH Among the many things it can mean is that the perception of Stack Overflow as the best place to get your question answered has deteriorated. But see my answer for the best guess at the _actual_ reason I have come up with.

Comment: It's not specified how exactly this data is generated. If it ignores deleted and/or closed questions, it could have something to do with all the attention the closing system has seen recently or perhaps changes to auto-deletion of questions.

Comment: @Dukeling The page implies that it is _historical_ data, not the age distribution of currently live posts. The same is obvious for the Traffic section.

Comment: One word: **saturation**.

Comment: @Dukeling - That is a very good point as well. If this metric does not include closed questions, then it could be very skewed by the use of mjolnir.

Comment: @TravisJ Doubting the inclusion of closed questions is truly a stretch. They are perfectly normal, visible questions, with the restriction of no new answers. The only plausible ambiguitiy regards deleted questions.

Comment: @Dukeling: The /site-analytics info specifically includes deleted posts: "Note that unlike most other sources, such as SEDE, this data includes information on deleted posts." from the [help center page on the privilege](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/site-analytics), just above the "Google Analytics" heading. Indeed, I think this is a large part of the privilege.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Great, thanks for the find. It was intuitively obvious to me (the page is about _historical events_, not the _current contents_ of SO), but it's great to have an authoritative confirmation.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

On the whole, I'd say that *post* growth rate is not so concerning if:

1. Quality questions are answered quickly and correctly, and
2. We aren't artificially limiting participation of programmers who have the ability, time and inclination to answer questions.

In fact, given the difficulties we've seen with floods of extremely poor questions, a bit of a break in growth might be welcome. I suspect that nearly every working programmer in the English-speaking world has visited Stack Overflow, so it's entirely possible we will hit a steady growth rate approximating the difference between [new programmers entering the field](https://stackoverflow.com/research/developer-survey-2015#profile-experience) and developers (such as myself) who move on to something else. Software continues to be a growth industry. It's just not growing as fast as Stack Overflow did in the first 5 year.

It's possible there's a natural limit to the number of questions that can be asked about a particular technology and we might be approaching that limit—especially on [popular tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/303704/1438). If so, it will be difficult or impossible to ask new and unique questions. This is doubly true for people entering the discipline since everyone has the same sorts of problems when they first start with a language. Programmers who are able to ask new questions in Java, C# or PHP have gotten themselves into obscure corners and probably have more-than-typical experience. So post rate might even grow slower than programmer growth rate. (This is one of the reasons we are looking hard at other content types such as [documentation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303865/warlords-of-documentation-a-proposed-expansion-of-stack-overflow).)

So let's go back to the two things that *might* be a concern. 2014 marked a turning point in answer rate:

[image: 2014 post types by week]

The blue line is questions (including deleted ones) and the green line is answers. At the start of the year, the spread was around 25k more answers a week than questions. By the end of the year, with roughly the same number of questions, the spread had shrunk to ~10k. That's about the same rate we've seen so far this year. (For reasons unknown to me, there was a large spike in activity leading up to the week of April 19, 2015. Temporarily, the answer rate was restored to something like it's pre-2014 rate.)

Currently, Stack Overflow isn't in the worst shape when it comes to [percent answered](https://stackexchange.com/sites#percentanswered), but whether the cause is a bunch of unanswerable questions or answering fatigue or something else entirely, questions are getting fewer answers of late. All other things being equal, getting fewer answers is a concern.

As a quick aside, we [delete unanswered and zero-scored questions after a year](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year). While this removes mostly unanswerable junk, it does make our public stats (which ignore deleted posts) look better than reality. Looking at [0 score questions by week last year](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/361457/posts-by-week?year=2014&score=0#graph) and excluding deleted posts, the "Uber-Tumbleweed" event horizon (one year ago) is pretty clear:

[image: 2014 posts by week]

We can safely assume there aren't many hidden gems in this group. But if you crank the question score up to something more reasonable, [like 2](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/361457/posts-by-week?year=2014&score=2#graph), the gap between answers and questions still shrunk in 2014. As a result, **I'm concerned questions aren't getting the answers they deserve** or at least not as many as in the past.

---

I'm also concerned that good programmers are discouraged from participating. We have some anecdotal evidence that experienced programmers who don't currently participate on Stack Overflow are intimidated by the process of getting started. This is one of the reasons I'm looking into a [mentoring system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/262292/1438). Talking to programmers who aren't active on the site we hear that it's really hard to ask questions that haven't already been asked and that the most commonly-encountered programming questions have already been well answered. So the old adage "write what you know" is generally poor advice on Stack Overflow.

There's a bit of a Catch 22: questions in less-frequented tags don't get as many good answers. I divided all first questions so far in 2015 (to avoid the automatic deletion mentioned above) into 4 more-or-less even bins by their primary tag's duplication rate:

```
          minimum     average           average average
          duplication question answered answer  answer  deleted closed
questions rate %      score    rate %   count   score   rate %  rate %
--------- ----------- -------- -------- ------- ------- ------- ------
   173686           3    -0.45     32.4    1.02    2.25    24.3   8.8
   209511           2    -0.22     31.8    1.03    1.95    20.2  13.0
   118739           1    -0.25     25.5    0.88    1.83    21.9   9.8
   160140           0    -0.18     17.6    0.62    1.48    23.3   7.8
```

As you can see, asking in tags with less duplication increases the odds that your question will do better in terms of voting. But your question is also much less likely to [get answered](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2008/09/ok-now-define-answered/) and the answers are less likely to be upvoted. (Note that deletion and closure rates are probably uncorrelated to duplication close rate. It's likely tags with high duplication rates are correlated with active [Mjölnir](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231212/1438)-wielding gold badge holders.<sup>[citation needed]</sup>)

Unfortunately, a new user faces a difficult choice:

1. Participate on popular tags where competition is fierce or
2. Participate on quieter tags where contributions tend to be ignored.

In either case, the difficulty is getting sufficient reputation to fully contribute to the site. It's probably a natural (not artificial) outcome of how the site works. But that doesn't mean we should give up on helping potentially valuable new contributors get started.

Comment: In the first graph shown, there is a noted change in answers per question in April. This was when Mjolnir was released. If you adjust the graph to show answers to *open* questions then would it show the same ratio as before? It seems there is the strong possibility that as duplicate questions became quickly closed answers decreased because no one could post them on those questions. However, that doesn't mean that the solution was not found by the OP. In order to determine that questions which had no answer were answered, wouldn't it be more accurate to exclude that situation?

Comment: @TravisJ: The second chart shows only currently open questions.  You can approximate the first graph in SEDE by looking at [open questions with score > 0](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/362882/posts-by-week?year=2014&score=0#graph) or [>1](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/362882/posts-by-week?year=2014&score=1#graph).

Comment: Thanks for those links. Hm, just looking at the difference between 2014 with no close date versus 2014 with close date, the adjustment seems to be linear (as in the same across the board) with no specific inflection at the targeted time of aprilish, or around week 15. Perhaps mjolnir didn't have anything to do with this. Is there any way to determine what the result of the throttle ban process would have been as far as impact goes?

Comment: @Jon What would be your explanation of the regularity in the spread between Q and A volume? Intuitively it would be more logical that the _ratio_ behaved like that. Why was the surplus of A over Q so stable even though the volume of Q was increasing?

Answer (score 36):

This question is of course entirely reasonable and interesting. However, I would like to start a digression about the phrasing of the title. "Is StackOverflow *declining*?" (emphasis mine) hints at an unspoken assumption that boundless growth is a need in and of itself; that a slowdown of growth is a problem, a sign of decline and that *something must be done about it*. But is that really the case? Wouldn't a decline actually consist of the loss of our ability to produce *quality* content that is useful to virtually all programmers?

I don't mean to suggest growth isn't important; that would be naive. However, naturalising the importance of growth leads to bad decisions, especially when there is a community involved. Questions like the one in the title make me anxious because they remind me of another community I love: Wikipedia, whose backers (i.e. the Wikimedia nonprofit, itself very worthy of respect) are lost at sea, sinking enormous amounts of effort and community goodwill in [futile measures](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Research:VisualEditor%27s_effect_on_newly_registered_editors/May_2015_study) to address a [supposed issue of growth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Wikipedia_Signpost/2012-01-02/Interview).

Comment: The kind of "importance of growth" thinking tends to get publicly-traded businesses in trouble too...

Comment: I agree with you @duplode, decline of questions on SO would also mean that most the bad quality questions are being moderated efficiently or the open questions are being closed very quickly with good quality of answers/solutions.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I'm not dismissing worrying conclusions, but merely warning about *hasty* worrying conclusions. I'm sorry you took this answer as strawan-making, that was not my intention. I did really mean it when I said above that your question was "entirely reasonable and interesting", or that suggesting that growth isn't important "would be naive". That's why I explicitly framed my answer as "a digression about the phrasing of the title", and left it to others to discuss the data you gathered.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Shallow interpretations don't need to be dignified (by myself or anyone else); too many people will jump at them anyway. I never claimed my answer presented the whole truth; it is obviously partial. I just chose to highlight a concern that might otherwise not enter the discussion. Your symmetrical concern about people going "la la la I can't hear you" is just as partial **and** just as valid -- they correct each other.

Comment: To summarize, too many people will jump at a conclusion that might otherwise not enter the discussion :) But don't get me wrong---I don't contest your entitlement to provide a response from one partial angle. I just exercise my entitlement to point it out as such.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik It's more like "too many people will jump at a conclusion that might otherwise go *unquestioned*". People will jump at conclusions anyway; that is what humans do (and Internet-dwelling humans are especially good at that). I just feel that bringing hasty conclusions under the spotlight might help dispelling them.

Answer (score 12):

### Edit

The conjecture originally presented in this answer is now disproved thanks to Jon Ericson. Here is the [time evolution of the volume of *non-closed, non-negative score* questions and answers to them](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/363003/non-closed-questions-by-month-and-answers-to-them?startYear=2010&endYear=2015&score=0#graph):

[image: Non-closed questions and answers by month]

It shows the same behavior as without the "good question" filter. In Q2, 2014 the volume of "good" questions dropped, and over the same period the volume of answers to those questions dropped even more severely. This effect persists to this day, but it was partially reversed in spring of this year.

---

### Original post

I have got a conjecture based on the peculiar behavior of the (answers *minus* questions) value over time—that is, of the surplus of answers over questions, regardless of the question volume itself. This is the time-series chart of the difference in the weekly volume of answers and questions:

[image: Questions minus answers over time]

Where the total volume of questions was increasing all the time, the A-Q difference was suprisingly steady. At the key event in 2014 the difference dropped, but then again maintained the new value, then slighly jumped up very recently. Still, the whole series can be very well approximated with horizontal lines (constants). I think this effect asks for an explanation, and here is my attempt.

Not all questions are alike. There is a specific category of questions which receives an inordinate amount of answers: beginner's questions, often re-asked tens and hundreds of times. Entry-level respondents pounce on those questions because the answer is known to many. Regardless of other types of questions, there may have been a constant number of these and a constant number of answers to them; these answers account for a large proportion of the surplus. If the above is true, then measures which reduced the number of such questions being posted, and also measures which reduced the number of *answers* to those questions, would both contribute to the reduction of the A-Q surplus.

Comment: It's interesting how distinct the drop-off appears when the data is broken down like that.  It kind of begs the question, did something happen to make it harder to post answers (or to make it harder to post easy but redundant questions) around April of 2014?

Comment: I haven't checked the exact timing, but the feature of the binding close vote (aka. the Golden Hammer) put a significant dent into the number of answers to duplicate questions.

Comment: Wouldn't the ratio of answers to questions make a more useful measure to look at then the difference? One could even remove closed questions from consideration, though maybe one should count dupe-closed questions as answered at least as much as the target...

Comment: @Deduplicator aroth already looked at the A/Q ratio and found nothing interesting; this is actually how I arrived at the observation I present here. What would be interesting is to look at just the closed questions and the time series of their weekly volume.

Comment: When was the rate limiting system changed to one question every 90 minutes for new users? The post about it was in may of 2014, wonder if it was implemented then, or sooner than that.

Comment: There it is: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/256084/400654 "As of last night.." may 27th 2014 so that's unlikely to be the cause.

Comment: "measures which reduced the number of _answers_ to those questions..." - [meta-tag:dupehammer] comes to mind, with the way it speeds up closing of "beginner's questions, often re-asked tens and hundreds of times"

Comment: @gnat That's exactly what I had in mind. It has been mentioned several times on this page (as "mjolnir, "golden hammer" and "binding close vote").

Answer (score 5):

*This paragraph referred to previous header ("...is SO declining?")*

In order to answer your question by *yes*, we would have to state, that **quantity** defines **quality**. Because in order to say that SO *is declining*, it would have to mean that the less questions mean less quality (maybe it was simply a poor choice of words or wrong understanding from my side - in that case, disregard this paragraph). Grenerally speaking, the community is striving to have the best questions and answers for them so everybody can find what he/she is looking for and more doesn't necessarily mean better.

---

*The rest is still valid*

It's fairly normal that people get bored of something and switch to something newer, fresher and better (from MySpace to Facebook for example). But there is nothing neither newer, nor fresher let alone *better* than StackOverflow. Otherwise we would all see that "new thing" right?

Or maybe take it this way - maybe human curiosity *surpassed* the speed of technology evolution - then we're seeing a cool phenomenon here - that currently we are as fast in asking about techno as new techno is coming out.

Or maybe people have finally figured out, how to use search...

Comment: I actually added the "declining" part of title later on, as a cheap news headline trick :)

Comment: Clever marketing :-)

Comment: of course "declining" can have different meanings.  is this even worth mentioning?

Comment: The question was different before it was edited...

Answer (score -7):

For the record, the graph shows that regarding the number of Qs asked on SO, that number has "gone flat", ie growth has stopped. The OP asks:

- "What would be a good explanation of this?"

Answer: it is absolutely impossible to truly know that.  This is precisely in the category of question of "why did the Dow Jones drop last week?" or "Why has Walmart grown and Sears has shrunk?" or "Why did Apple lose half their market share to Samsung?" or "Why has the oil price dropped recently?"  It is

## absolutely impossible

to "really" answer such questions.

Point: it **is possible** there is some simple, obvious, secular explanation for the specific change in the graph at that specific time.  For example, it could be that (purely an example) on that day a new feature was introduced that eliminates Spanish language questions: in that case it would be utterly reasonable to say "oh there's a specific secular explanation".  It would seem **there is not such a specific secular explanation** because nobody has given one here.  So we can set aside a secular explanation (unless someone here has an "ah ha" moment and suddenly realises something dramatically changed on that time), and we can copy and paste ourselves and state, again, with total confidence that: It is

## absolutely impossible

to "really" answer such questions".  (Such questions as "why did the Dow Jones drop last week?" or "Why has Walmart grown and Sears has shrunk?" or "Why did Apple lose half their market share to Samsung?" or "Why has the oil price dropped recently?" or "Why has SO's growth in questions-aksed ended?")

## HOWEVER,

There is an absolutely critical observation to be made here.

It is this dead simple:

• every single (no exceptions) dotcom, which has existed so far, **has had a phase of growth of metrics** (such as "posts made" or "reviews posted" or "users joined"), and then, **that growth phase has ended** at some particular point in time.

Note that this is so absolutely and utterly normal ("every time so far") a part of the dotcom business, that, it's an utterly normal thing one talks about in relation to dotcoms.  When will the growth phase end, do you guess we're at the end of the growth phase here, what do you think is better, the pre- or post- sellout, and so on.

Indeed it would be astoundingly and wholly remarkable if, SE was the known universe's first dotcom, where, the growth phase has not ended.  SO's "run" before the growth phase ended (what was it - 6 years? the wholly useless charts above do not have years indicated on the X axis) is utterly typical and unsurprising.

The only "answer" to your question here, is, that the question is somewhat misguided.  All you are saying is "Oh, look at that, as it turned out SO's growth phase lasted X months (80 .. whatever) and it ended in spring of 2014 (whatever)"

Then regarding that observation, you're saying ....... what?

You could *comment* on it in different ways like "that seems typical" or "Huh - imagine!" or "Man they are taking a risk going for a sellout after rather than before the growth-end" or "what a nice run it was" ... or whatever.

And - by all means - with these "metrics" you can and should certainly look at others: so, things like "ah hah! but if we look at comments made, it's still solidly in the growth phase!" ... or whatever.  Do that.

Finally, as mentioned: SE, like Google, is **an advertising business**.  If you're thinking of it more "as a business", then, trivially and obviously, one would look at ad revenues, and see whether **that** is still in the growth phase; that's more of the "real" metric.  (The "other" metrics are just what analysts use to guess what will happen to the actual measure (ie, money) of the business.)

Comment: There are plenty secular explanations proposed, and in fact all is converging to a conclusion that bad-quality questions from new users constituted a significant proportion of all questions. Measures to reduce such questions were so successful that their effect is visible in the total question volume.

Comment: Marko - if so, fine.  (1) that is utterly, staggeringly, vague.  can you or someone (if anyone cares - I don't) state clearly "what changed" (2) can you give the exact date, ideally time of day, when this change happened, and thence see if there is a correlation with the graph in question.  if this is fairly clearly correct -- there would seem on this page to be an **utter lack of general agreement about a secular explanation** -- then fantastic, you've explained the step-change with a secular explanation.

Comment: Note however that, as explained at vast length, 100.00% of dotcoms have a point where "growth ends".  This will (or has already been) true for SE as well.  (I could not care less about when that will / has already happened; but if that's the question that interests you .. there you go; the issue is clarified.)

Comment: I refer to your statement `because nobody has given one here`---several people have in fact given several explanations, and additionally all of them revolve around the same period and the same type of changes. There has not been just _one_ change, but several, each of which may contribute to the joint effect.

Comment: If that's what you feel, then the question is answered for you.  I cannot see the slightest, at all, general consensus, nor, nexus of reasons.  You state *"given several explanations, and additionally all of them revolve around the same period"*.  Then tell me this.  What is the count of those explanations in that set?  3? 4? what?  Can you list them?

Comment: You've used the word "secular" several times; what do you mean by it?